# Why does ZF natural number construction not simply use n+1={n} instead of n+1=n $\cup$ {n}?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

From [Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)

> n+1=n $\cup$ {n}

i.e.

- 0 = {}
- 1 = {{}}
- 2 = {{},{{}}}
- etc

It seems to me that a simpler, equally valid definition would be

> n+1={n}

i.e.

- 0 = {}
- 1 = {0} = {{}}
- 2 = {1} = {{{}}}
- etc

Why is the ZF definiton preferred over mine?

(The only "advantage" I can think of is that in ZF, $|n|=n$, but this strikes me as being circular reasoning.)

Comment: Try to define "$n<m$" in both cases. Which one is easier? Try to define "$X$ has size $n$". Which one is easier?

Comment: A similar comment to Jonathan's: consider that the cardinality of $n$ is $n$ in this construction. In yours, all the naturals are singletons and are all isomorphic. If you want natural numbers to be a special case of ordinals, which you *do*, then having everything a singleton with no concept of order is useless

Comment: Have you tried proving the Peano Axioms using your definition? How is addition of natural numbers defined? How do we get 1+1 = 2 with your definition? As @FShrike said, the Ordinals are a very important Class in set theory, and so it is convenient to have the natural numbers be a special case.

Comment: With the usual definition, every integer is a transitive set, and the $\lt$ relation simply *is* membership: $m \lt n \iff m\in n$. With your definition, $m \in n \iff n = m+1$, and you still have to define $m\lt n$ — for example, as $m\in \operatorname{TC}(n) =$ transitive closure of $x$ — and show it’s a total order.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85672/the-history-of-set-theoretic-definitions-of-mathbb-n